# Google COLAB free version saving Keras trained model

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I saved keras trained model in google colab free version

```
 model.save("my_model.h5")
```

i tried to retrieve model using below method

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

But it is throwing errors

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'my_model.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

**will i able to retrive saved model from free google colab version**, can you any help on this
I checked similar question in stackoverflow, i think these answers belongs to colab pro version

Otherwise, do i have to save model in specific path to local drive while training?

Comment: Yes, i followed as below,                                                                                                        

>from google.colab import drive
>drive.mount('/content/drive') '**

Comment: What is time difference between saving and loading model. It's because you are saving model colab environment and colab environment deletes file when runtime terminates.

Comment: @PSKP  yeterday started the  6:30 ist and tired to to open 7:30 ist morning. I am suspecting this could be th reason. can you let me know how to save the Deep Learning models to local drive in this case

Comment: I added answer which will solve your problem. check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is Problem

You are storing your model in runtime not in your google drive. After 12 hour runtime automatically deleted with data. So we have to save model in google drive.

## How to store to Google Drive

**First connect to google drive**

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Now you will find file explorer at left side which has `drive` directory. When you go inside that directory, it will take you to google drive.

Suppose I want to put my data in drive `My Drive` then

```py
from keras.models import load_model

MODEL_PATH = './drive/My Drive/model.h5'

# Now save model in drive
model.save(MODEL_PATH)

# Load Model
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
```

When you open your drive, you will find file `model.h5` in drive.